# openfire offline file transfer requires build every time

Tags: java, android, xmpp, chat, openfire

As Openfire does not support file transfer to off-line user. To implement this i made a plugin.It functions like this:

(Suppose **client A** sends a file to **Client B**)

1.Client sends a request using post method with file.

2.**on Server** my plugin receives that request and writes that file into a temp directory(**the temp directory exists under web directory.**)

3.Now my plugin sends response to **client A** with a path of file (example:`"http://10.0.2.2:9090/temp/ppp.png"`).

4.Now **client A** sends this file path to **Client B**(By simple xmpp text message transfer).

**The Problem is** when a new file comes into **temp or any folder under web** of openfire then this file will **not available for http request**.I need to **build openfire every time** to make that new file available for download or for http.

But **I want new file available for http (for download) without build openfire every time.**

Comment: Are you using XEP-0066 ?

Comment: I am using openfire code in eclipse..

Comment: This seems like a permissions problem?  Did you ever figure this out?  Also is your plugin available?

Comment: hey @VibhorBhardwaj need help in Chat app.. any help appreciated

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Could you please share the plugin that you wrote with us?